# Backbone.js - Filtering a collection and resetting view

Tags: backbone.js

I'm using Backbone.js with jquery and rails. I have a model Player and collection Players. On init I load all Players to view with PlayersView.

I would like to add the ability to filter players by Position and re-render the PlayersView accordingly. I have given it a shot but currently it just reloads all Players and doesn't filter. Please let me know if/how I can revise! Thanks.

```
/* Models/Collections */
var Player = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function() {
    return this.id ? '/projects/' + this.id : '/projects'; 
  },

  initialize: function(){
  },
});

var Players = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Player,
  url: '/players.json',

  sortPosition : function(position){
    return _(this.filter(function(data) {
        return data.get("position") == position;
    }));
  },
});
```

and

```
// view // players //
var PlayersView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#players',

  events: {
    'click .position': 'sort',  
  },

  initialize: function(){
    this.bind("reset", this, 'render', 'sort'); // remember: every function that uses 'this' as the current object should be in here
    this.render();      
  },
  render: function(){
    $('#players').show();

    players.each(function(player){
      firstname = player.get('first_name');
      lastname = player.get('last_name');
      position = player.get('position');
      team = player.get('team');
      $('#players-list').append('<li><span class="player-position">' + position + '</span><span class="player-name">' + firstname + ' ' + lastname + '</span><span class="player-team">' + team + '</span></li>')
    });

    return this;
  },
  sort: function(e){
    var position = $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-pos');
    this.render(players.sortPosition(position));
  },
});
```

It seems like my problem is that i'm calling 'render' again which takes all players and doesn't accept a filtered set. Let me know if i can help with more code!

Thanks much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i have no time to fully debug your code,
since there is also a few pieces (declaration) missing.

but i already see a few things that can be improved,

1) you pass `players.sortPosition(position)` into the render function, but your render function does not accept any arguments.

i think it is better to do them separately,
replace your view's collection by the sorted collection, and invoke render again:

```
sort: function(e) {
    this.collection = players.sortPosition(position);
    this.render();
}
```

2) you have a weird construction of the eventbinding in your initialize function

i've never seen it like this:

```
initialize: function(){
    this.bind("reset", this, 'render', 'sort'); // remember: every function that uses 'this' as the current object should be in here
    this.render();      
},
```

what exactly is your intention?, if you just want to use `this` within the bound function,
you can use `_.bindAll(this, "function1", function2", ... , "render");` if you want to bind to a certain event like "reset" i would write: `this.bind('reset', this.render, this);`

Comment: This was kind of just a sloppy question. Sorry! I kind of jumped the gun and hadn't read enough yet. That's basically what I did tho.Thanks.

Comment: To make this simpler and build off what @Sander did you could do this in your initialize: this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this); and in your sort method do: this.collection.reset(players.sortPosition(position));  Then remove the call to render in your sort method.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is post is a bit old, but you can use Backbone's comparator to sort the collection.

```
 var Players = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: Player,
   url: '/players.json',

   initialize : function(){
     _.bindAll(this);
     this.fetch();
   },
   comparator: function(player){
     return player.get('position')
   }
 });
```

This way, whenever you create an instance of this collection, the models in the collection are sorted by position automatically.